# Is it possible to let Fog interact with the material's opacity?

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

I am working on a project that displays buildings. **The requirement is to let the building gradually fade out (transparent) based on the distance between the camera and the buildings.** Also, this effect has to follow the camera's movement.

I consider using `THREE.Fog()`, but the Fog seems can only change the material's color.
[image: Buildings with White Fog enabled]
Above is a picture of the building with white fog.

- The buildings are in tiles, each tile is one single geometry (I merged all the buildings into one) using

  `var bigGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  bigGeometry.merge(smallGeometry);`
- The purple/blue color thing is the ground, and `ground.material.fog = false;`. So the ground won't interact with the fog.

My question is:

- Is it  possible to let the fog interact with the building's material's opacity instead of color? (more white translate to more transparent)
- Or should I use Shader to control the material's opacity based on distance to the camera? But I have no idea of how to do this.
- I also considered adding `alphaMap`. If so, each building tile have to map an alphaMap and all these alphaMap have to interact with the camera's movement. It's going to be a tons of work.

So any suggestions?

Best Regards,
Arthur

Comment: Transparency in WebGL is complicated and I'm not sure this is the right way to get the visual effect you want. Perhaps match the fog color to the sky's color so the boxes in the distance match that? But if you are sure you want to use opacity, I'd forget about Fog and just assign each box an opacity value based on its distance from the camera, like `box.material.opacity = Math.max(0, (100 - distance) / 100);`.

Comment: Hi @DonMcCurdy, The reason why I can't change each building box's opacity is that I merged a chunk of building together to a single geometry and that single geometry can only apply with one material (correct me if wrong). The reason why I merge building together is that there will be around 1k to 5k buildings on screen, merge buildings will help keep high FPS. While before I merge all the buildings, the FPS is only 12 - 30, after is 56 - 60.

Comment: Hm, ok yes that makes sense.

Comment: I would use the option with control the material's opacity, for that you have to change a built-in material. One approach of how to achieve that you can find in this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/in-the-orb-shaders/3286?u=prisoner849).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the OP. After spending some time reading how to use Three.js's Shader material. I got some code that is working as desired.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/yingcai/4dxnysvq/

The basic idea is:

1. Create an Uniform that contains controls.target (Vector3 position).
2. Pass vertex position attributes to varying in the Vertex Shader. So
   that the Fragment Shader can access it.
3. Get the distance between each vertex position and controls.target. Calculate alpha value based on the distance.
4. Assign alpha value to the vertex color.

Another important thing is: Because the fade out mask should follow the camera move, so don't forget to update the control in the uniforms every frame.

```
// Create uniforms that contains control position value.
uniforms = {
    texture: {
      value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/water.jpg")
    },
    control: {
      value: controls.target
    }
  };

// In the render() method.
// Update the uniforms value every frame.
uniforms.control.value = controls.target;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: I suspect there are probably easier/prettier ways to solve this than opacity. In particular, note that partially-opaque buildings will show other buildings behind them. To address that, consider using a gradient or some other scene background, and choosing a fog color to match that, rather than using opacity. But for the sake of trying it...

Here's how to alter an object's opacity based on its distance. This doesn't actually require `THREE.Fog`, I'm not sure how you would use the fog data directly. Instead I'll use `THREE.NodeMaterial`, which (as of three.js r96) is fairly experimental. The alternative would be to write a custom shader with `THREE.ShaderMaterial`, which is also fine.

```
const material = new THREE.StandardNodeMaterial();
material.transparent = true;
material.color = new THREE.ColorNode( 0xeeeeee );

// Calculate alpha of each fragment roughly as:
// alpha = 1.0 - saturate( distance / cutoff )
//
// Technically this is distance from the origin, for the demo, but
// distance from a custom THREE.Vector3Node would work just as well.
const distance = new THREE.Math2Node(
  new THREE.PositionNode( THREE.PositionNode.WORLD ),
  new THREE.PositionNode( THREE.PositionNode.WORLD ),
  THREE.Math2Node.DOT
);
const normalizedDistance = new THREE.Math1Node(
  new THREE.OperatorNode(
    distance,
    new THREE.FloatNode( 50 * 50 ),
    THREE.OperatorNode.DIV
  ),
  THREE.Math1Node.SAT
);
material.alpha = new THREE.OperatorNode(
  new THREE.FloatNode( 1.0 ),
  normalizedDistance,
  THREE.OperatorNode.SUB
);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/donmccurdy/1L4s9e0c/

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot of solution]

Comment: Very infromative!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - a few years later - and solved it with the .onBeforeCompile function which is maybe more convenient to use.
There is a great tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@pailhead011/extending-three-js-materials-with-glsl-78ea7bbb9270)

The code itself is simple and could be easily changed for other materials. It just uses the fogFactor as alpha value in the material.

Here the material function:

```
alphaFog() {
const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial();
material.onBeforeCompile = function (shader) {

  const alphaFog =
      `
      #ifdef USE_FOG
        #ifdef FOG_EXP2
          float fogFactor = 1.0 - exp( - fogDensity * fogDensity * vFogDepth * vFogDepth );
        #else
          float fogFactor = smoothstep( fogNear, fogFar, vFogDepth );
        #endif
        gl_FragColor.a = saturate(1.0 - fogFactor);
      #endif
  `

  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
      '#include <fog_fragment>', alphaFog
  );

  material.userData.shader = shader;
};


material.transparent = true
return material;
}
```

and afterwards you can use it like

```
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, this.alphaFog());
```